# Doxygen : skip some classes / structs

Tags: doxygen

I use Doxygen to generate my documentation but it adds documentation for the structs that does not have any documentation.

I use HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES in my Doxyfile.in, but I still see some documentation.

Is there another way to explain to Doxygen to not generate any documentation for a class/struct ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS tag.

The documentation says:

```
The EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS tag can be used to specify one or more symbol names
(namespaces, classes, functions, etc.) that should be excluded from the
output. The symbol name can be a fully qualified name, a word, or if the
wildcard * is used, a substring. Examples: ANamespace, AClass,
AClass::ANamespace, ANamespace::*Test

Note that the wildcards are matched against the file with absolute path, so to
exclude all test directories use the pattern */test/*
```